# RecyclerView onViewDetachedFromWindow causes problems

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want **onViewDetachedFromWindow** to not being called. In other words, I don't want my views to be detached, just attached. Basically I want it to work as a ScrollView. Why? We're having problems with a third party view that occurs as soon as onViewDetachedFromWindow is called. Performance wise it's not great, but at least it will work for now.

I've tried:

**MainActivity.java**

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0,20);
```

**MyRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(final NUKijkPlayerHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(null);
   // Tried uncommenting the super as well: //super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(null);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to remove   `super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(null);`

Comment: yes I did. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want recycling mechanics, simply replace recyclerview with linearlayout inside scrollview

Answer (score -2):

use `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView`

Comment: Mind to explain why this will help?